# Dynamic client with JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cxf

With CXF 2.7.7, I can [generate dynamic clients](http://docs.huihoo.com/apache/cxf/2.2.4/dynamic-clients.html) to call a web service:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dynamicClientFactory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dynamicClientFactory.createClient(wsdlURL);
http.getAuthorization().setUserName("username");
http.getAuthorization().setPassword("password");
Object arg = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.foo.Arg").newInstance();
Object[] response = client.invoke("someMethodName", arg);
```

In particular, I can reflectively instantiate and populate the generated classes.

Can a similar effect be achieved using the JAX-WS APIs?

Or alternatively, can I get hold of a javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider for a Client generated using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory?

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the BindingProvider for?   If it's just for the RequestContext, the Client object already has methods to obtain that.  (although any key/value you set on that would need to be using the CXF  keys, not the JAX-WS keys)   The getConduit call is there as well if you need to configure conduit specific properties.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the way to go. I also use a SOAPHandler to capture the actual SOAP messages that go in/out, but I gather I can use Interceptors in CXF for the same effect? I was just hoping if there was a simple way to do it via the JAX-WS API, I could change less of my existing code.